# sonarqube-8.6.1 unable to start in windows

Tags: sonarqube, devops, cicd

I am unable to start the sonarqube in my local windows machine, Getting the below error,
[image]

I have set java path and it's working fine,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.6/requirements/requirements/ which describes as the following: -

> Prerequisite
>
> The only prerequisite for running SonarQube is to have Java (Oracle JRE 11 or OpenJDK 11) installed on your machine.

> Supported Platforms
>
> Java
>
> SonarQube scanners require version 8 or 11 of the JVM
>
> SonarQube server requires version 11. Versions beyond Java 11 are not officially supported.

Then this is a root cause why we face this failure message when we run it against the  **JDK** version `8`

I would suggest to download the **JDK** version `11` and use it so that we meet the **SonarQube Server** requirement.